# How to sample via blocked Gibbs the conjugate normal model?

Tags: gibbs, nonparametric-bayes

i am trying to sample the two dimensional parameter $\theta=(\mu,\sigma^2)$, for the Normal model. I have the full conditionals being for the mean:

$\pi(\mu_{j}|\ldots) \sim N\left(\frac{\xi_{j}\lambda_{j}}{s+m_{j}\lambda_{j}},\frac{1}{s+m_{j}\lambda_{j}}\right),\quad j=1,\ldots n$,

and for the variance

$\pi(\lambda_{j}|\ldots) \sim Ga\left(\epsilon + \frac{m_{j}}{2}, \epsilon + \frac{\sum_{d_{i}=j}(y_{i}-\mu_{j})^{2}}{2}\right),\quad j=1,\ldots,n$,

where $\lambda=1/\sigma^2$.

What i don't know is how to perform blocked Gibbs (in R) because in both equations i need the other variate from the other variable, that is:

for $\mu_{j}$ i need $\lambda_{j}$ and for $\lambda_{j}$ i need $\mu_{j}$. Maybe its a simple method but i couldnt find anything that explains good the method.

Comment: You start with some $\lambda^{[0]}$, and sample $(\mu_j^{[1]}|y,\lambda_j^{[0]},...)$. Then when you have your $\mu's$, sample $(\lambda_j^{[1]}|y,\mu_j^{[1]},...)$, and around you go.

Comment: @Glen_b yes you are right and thank you for mentioning it. But i guess my bigger problem is the following. This is nice for one iteration of the MCMC, but how to make the algorithm, in the second iteration use as initial value for $\lambda_{j}^{[2]}$ the previous $\lambda_{j}^{[1]}$ and go on. Actually i don't know if it matters, but in every iteration of the MCMC the dimension of $\mu, \lambda$ may change.

Comment: You don't need $\lambda^{[1]}_j$ for $\lambda^{[2]}_j$ at all, you need it for $\mu^{[2]}_j$. On the changing dimension -- that's rather important information. Then you need to use something more sophisticated than a plain Gibbs; exactly what depends on the model and how you want to try to implement it. For example, you might have indicator variables that say whether particular $\mu$'s and $\lambda$'s are present and include those in your model and sampler (you will have to integrate some variables out - especially the variables that the indicator can set to 0), ... ctd

Comment: (ctd) ...  or you could do something like a reversible jump sampler, which can deal with changing dimension.

Comment: @Glen_b thank you very much for your time. When i 'll make it i let you know where my problem was.